# Failure of Multisystem after first install on Cinnamon Mint 17.1 and 17.2 64-bit

Tags: multi-boot, linux-mint

I installed MultiSystem so I could create a toolkit USB drive, as I have done on previous Xubuntu and Lubuntu machines, following http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/ .

However, doesn't seem to work with Mint Cinnamon 17.1 (and, later, 17.2) as on the first attempt to select the USB drive (pic #5 from the web page cited above), I see this error dialog:

> The terminal (VteTerminal) widget requires a version of gtkdialog
>   built with libvte.

Closing that dialog box closes the app.

Where could I go from here? Don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is mentioned in the page
[linux mint 17.1 multisystem error, The terminal (VteTerminal) widget requires a version of gtkdialog built with libvte.](http://kee520.blogspot.fr/2015/08/linux-mint-171-multisystem-error.html).
The solution involves compiling multisystem.

The author tells of his epic fight to install multisystem, terminating by :

> So I tried to purge all instances of multisystem, then did a fresh
>   install of the newest version, which showed the gtkdialog error again.
>
> This time, using dutch webpage solution, I compiled gtkdialog using
>   vte as follows,

```
-> wget https://gtkdialog.googlecode.com/files/gtkdialog-0.8.3.tar.gz
-> decompress file to '~/Download/gtkdialog-0.8.3/', and cd into the folder
-> sudo apt-get install gtk+-2.0-dev
-> sudo ./configure
look for VTE... no
-> sudo apt-get install libvte-dev
-> sudo ./configure
look for VTE... yes
-> sudo make
-> sudo make install
-> gtkdialog -v
```

This should show:

> gtkdialog version 0.8.3 release (C) 2003-2007
>   Laszlo Pere, 2011-2012 Thunor Built with additional support for: VTE.

Comment: Urk. Thank you for the precise and intimidating answer.

Comment: @K7AAY: You had better decide what to do with this answer. If it's too intimidating, then get help or try to follow the above directions. This procedure is not very risky.

Comment: Your comment,  sir,  exceeds the bounds of commonly accepted manners.

Comment: I was only trying to encourage you to try this procedure, but you took this as an insult. I apologize if my comment contained any kind of insult, and would like to understand more about your feelings in the matter. Please remember that I'm only trying to help and do not receive any kind of return for my efforts except appreciation.

Comment: Excellent solution. Only the site where is gtkdialog is different: wget https://code.google.com/archive/p/gtkdialog/downloads/gtkdialog-0.8.3.tar.gz and in the third line you wrote sudo apt-get intsall gtk+-2.0-dev
it should be: sudo apt-get install gtk+-2.0-dev